# Retrieve object user metadata in S3 - aws sdk v3 php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm looking to retrieve user-defined meta-data from objects in my S3 bucket, from the php sdk.

As per [Editing Object Meta Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingtheMetadataofanObject.html), User metadata is stored with the object and returned with it, and begin with "x-amz-meta-"

I have defined user metadata on objects through the console like "x-amz-meta-test", at both upload time, and adding it after the upload (through web console, not the upload API).

The test metadata is never returned. I always get the same system metadata. That is, I get only the following keys in @metadata:

**Folder**

```
statuscode
effectiveUri
headers
   x-amz-id-2
   x-amz-request-id
   date
   x-amz-bucket-region
   content-type
   transfer-encoding
   server
```

**Objects**

```
Key
LastModified
   date
   timezone_type
   timezone
ETag
Size
StorageClass
```

However, to achieve this in other languages, a simple method call is involved.

[Get User Metadata in Android SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getUserMetadata%28%29)

[Get User Metadata in Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getUserMetadata%28%29)

How do I go about accomplishing the same task in the PHP SDK?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with v3 AWS SDK for PHP. After some research and testing, I determined I could use `headObject`:

```
<?php
    $headers = $s3->headObject(array(
      "Bucket" => $bucket,
      "Key" => $key
    ));

    print_r($headers->toArray());
?>
```

Example output with System-Defined Metadata and other identifying information REMOVED:

```
Array
(
/* REMOVED */
    [Metadata] => Array
        (
            [orderdate] => Mon, 31 Aug 2015 19:03:52 +0000
            [color] => green
            [fruit] => apple
            [price] => 99.95
        )
/* REMOVED */
    [@metadata] => Array
        (
            [statusCode] => 200
            [effectiveUri] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/REMOVED/REMOVED
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [x-amz-id-2] => REMOVED
                    [x-amz-request-id] => REMOVED
                    [date] => Wed, 02 Sep 2015 04:43:02 GMT
                    [x-amz-meta-orderdate] => Mon, 31 Aug 2015 19:03:52 +0000
                    [x-amz-meta-color] => green
                    [x-amz-meta-fruit] => apple
                    [x-amz-meta-price] => 99.95
                    [last-modified] => Wed, 02 Sep 2015 04:11:13 GMT
                    [etag] => "REMOVED"
                    [x-amz-storage-class] => REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
                    [accept-ranges] => bytes
                    [content-type] => application/octet-stream
                    [content-length] => 80771
                    [server] => AmazonS3
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works perfectly. Thank you for the detailed example